# iOS - kill the app with a button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, exit

I have an app that runs for a while, but needs to be reset every day, because it's lifecycle is a bit different than most other apps. It seems that the easiest way to do this is to kill the app and re-launch it.

I found a solution that kills the app when the home button is tapped:

> In your application's Info.plist, add a boolean key
>   UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend with the value YES

This is not something that I want to do. I need to give the user an option to kill/reset the app before it is used. I can certainly ask the user to double tap the home key and kill the app with a long press>x. Yet this is too complex for some users.

Another simple solution would be to have a button do something crashworthy, like divide by 0, although I'm not sure if the app store would penalize my app for "crashing" every single day for all users.

**Has anyone found a way to add an "exit" button to an iPhone app? In android, I could do system.exit(0), which worked. What's the iPhone alternative?**

Comment: Yes, the App Store will penalize you for this *big time*. Only the user is supposed to decide when the application should close.

Comment: Maybe if you will explain why do you need to kill the app, people will have ideas how can you achieve the same effect with out doing so?

Comment: If this is for your lucid dreaming app ( http://luciddreamingapp.com/iphone-app/), then I can't really see a reason you need to quit the app.

Comment: The issue that I ran with the lucid dreaming app is that it's really difficult to differentiate between an app pause and stop. In the morning, the app is stopped, and it would be restarted next evening. Resetting the app would make it a lot easier to figure out when to start/stop collecting data. I'm using a similar approach in the Android app, and it works well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

iOS Human Interface Guide says - 
[Don’t Quit Programmatically](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW27)

> Never quit an iOS application programmatically because people tend to
>   interpret this as a crash. However, if external circumstances prevent
>   your application from functioning as intended, you need to tell your
>   users about the situation and explain what they can do about it.
>   Depending on how severe the application malfunction is, you have two
>   choices. ...

---

`exit(0);` can terminate the application (0 is a normal code), but Apple don't like this approach, and the application would be rejected in review.